# Why Firebase (onAuthStateChanged) does not see a Google signup user (with signInWithCredential)?

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-signin, react-native-firebase

So I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TdyiHng-1Ks) on how to sign in a user with [rnfirebase](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/social-auth#google) and google signup. And it works fine. Here is the code:

```js
const googleSignUp = async () => {
  // Get the users ID token
  const { idToken } = await GoogleSignin.signIn();

  // Create a Google credential with the token
  const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);

  // Sign-in the user with the credential
  const user = auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);

  return { idToken, user };
};
```

(Let me note here, that the app has already a sign in with email and password way, with Firebase).

Then I realized that the user cannot change his name, email or delete his account.
Looking deeper, I found out that the `onAuthStateChanged(firebase.auth, async (user) => ...` returns `null` for the user.

I've seen in some older answers that if you use Google sign up, you need to sign up the user with `signInWithCredential`, which I use, so this in not the issue.

Could it be a problem that for email/password sign in, I use code from `Firebase web` and not from `rnfirebase`? Although I already had a combination of those, using the push notifications from `rnfirebase`.

Can someone explain why I get this behavior, and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you use both the `react-native-firebase` library (which wraps the native iOS and Android SDKs) and the JavaScript Web SDK for Firebase in your app.

If that is the case, both indeed have a separate sign-in state, and signing into one won't fire `onAuthStateChanged` listeners on the other.

You'll have to pick one SDK to authenticate with Firebase, and then use that for both providers.

Comment: Hello Frank! Thanks for your response. Yes indeed, I use the `JavaScript Web SDK`to sign in with email and the `@react-native-firebase/auth` to sing in with Google. I'll try to use one of them. Thanks again!